# Detect hand using CIDetector

Tags: ios, core-image

Is there any way to detect hand or palm using CIDetector? I have googled but only face detection is found, is there any way to do it? please help.

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 8 you can detect QR codes and rectangles too, but alas, not hands or palms.

Comment: not a valid answer :(

Comment: It is a valid answer, it is a long version of "no."